# Java could not find or load main class when I use -cp

Tags: java, class, classpath

I have a problem.
I try to run my java program with the library.
When I use

```
java com/myProg
```

it works.

But when I try to pass classpath it can't find or load main class

```
java -cp com/lib/lid.jar com/myProgram
```

error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class myProgram
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myProgram

Comment: Try adding current directory to classpath like `java -cp com/lib/lid.jar;. com/myProgram` (instead of `;` you may need other separator like `:`, depending on OS).

Comment: @Pshemo thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying after the -cp option only the root of the working directory and don't include the package name there. If you're running the java command from the dir of `/com` 's location, `-cp . com/myProgram` will be enough,otherwise you'll need the fully qualified name after the classpath.
Not sure of the necessity of the .jar file, you stated that first you ran only via 
`java com/myProg`.